# How to require one permission *or* another permission to access a ServiceStack web service?

Tags: c#, permissions, servicestack

The following code demonstrates how to require that a user have two separate permissions in order to be granted use of a web service:

```
[RequiredPermission("permission1", "permission2")]
[Route("/client/{clientId}/users", "GET")]
public class UsersClientRequest : IReturn<List<Dto.User>>
{
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to grant use of a web service if they have one permission *or* another using ServiceStack?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RequiresAnyRole and RequiresAnyPermission are 2 new attributes that have [just been added to ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/pull/726) that does what you want.

They will be available in the next NuGet release of ServiceStack v3.9.50+.

Comment: Great, thank you, I'll be looking forward to the new release.  In the interim, is there any sort of workaround?  I seem to be on version 3.9.17.0.

Comment: 3.9.17 is very old and we don't support older versions. But if you ever need something like this you can simply just [copy and paste it](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/RequiresAnyPermission.cs) to your own project and use it as-is.

Comment: God bless open source!!  Thank you, @mythz.  Copied this into my solution until the upgrade becomes available.